# iTunes Producer unable to get password from my keychain

Tags: mac, imac, password, keychain, itunes-producer

When I try to open iTunes Producer, I get an error stating, "We are unable to retrieve your password from the security keychain." I recently deleted the folder in my keychain library while trying to fix another keychain problem that I was having. The previous problem was that a large number of programs (calendar, chrome, etc.) had problems with the keychain. I fixed that problem by resetting my iCloud and computer keychains.

I am currently running OS X Yosemite on my iMac and have not had any problems prior to these two keychain problems. I haven't downloaded anything that was even remotely dangerous. I've run keychain first aid and reinstalled the program. I've also deleted the library file again. At this point, I have no idea what to do. I've gone through and opened every other program on my computer with no problems at all.

Thank you for any advice. I've spent the last two days googling and I guess that I'm the only one to have ever encountered this problem :(

Comment: The same problem here...
did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Keychain has corrupted.

Do you get this error *"Preferences Error: Could not load Accounts preference pane."*

I have a solution here

Search for "Keychain Access" and a window as shown in the picture above would appear. Select the account which is troubling you.
Delete it/them and restart.
Moreover you can review any used accounts and remove them from here too.

Details [here](http://madwithmac.blogspot.in/2015/06/solved-cant-open-account-preferences.html)

Comment: The problem isn't that a keychain is corrupted.  It's that the program isn't creating a new individual key.  I've created an entirely new keychain, I've deleted all of the keys, and I've reinstalled the application.  Nothing seems to change it.  The computer is only about 3 months old, and I use it purely for work purposes, so I'm just going to back up all of my documents and reset it to factory settings.  I would love to know if there are any other options in case it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

This step by step solved my problem ([source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7128012?start=0&tstart=0))

1. Quit iTunes Producer.
2. Launch Terminal.app. On your Mac computer, locate Terminal.app by clicking Finder > Applications > Utilities.
3. Type the following in Terminal: defaults remove com.apple.iTunesProducer ITunesUsername
4. Hit Enter on your keyboard.
5. Launch iTunes Producer.